# How to insert character in between a string in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I need help in inserting a character inside a string, e.g.:

`031613 05:39 AM`

The output should be:

`03/16/13 05:39 AM`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `STUFF`

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(20) = '031613 05:39 AM'

SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@String,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/')
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15786)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)?

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(50) = '031613 05:39 AM'

SELECT  @String,
        SUBSTRING(@String,1,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@String,3,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@String,3,2) + SUBSTRING(@String,7,LEN(@String)-6)
```

### [SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15784)

Comment: Thanks!Can you also use STUFF T-SQL for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

use can also do like this.. but quite big solution.

```
declare @T varchar(100)= '031613 05:39 AM'
declare @result varchar(100) =''

;with CTE
as
(
Select 0 as startIndex, 2 as endIndex 
union all
select convert(int, endIndex) as startIndex , endIndex+2 as endIndex from CTe where endIndex < charindex(' ',@T)
)
select top 3 @result += substring(@T,startIndex+1, endIndex-startIndex)+'/' from CTe
select substring( @result,0,len(@result))
```